# Can I dynamically change the session length based on a logged in users role in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, session-timeout

I am wondering if this is possible. Have looked around and not found much luck. Basically I want one user with role1 to get a 20 minute session. When a user with a role2 logs in I want their session to be 60 minutes.

I needed this in asp.net project. The code was as simple as...

```
Session.Timeout = 60;
```

The 60 was in minutes. The Session is from HttpSessionStateBase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can invalidate a session manually after a timespan.